# Problemas na condição do while -R

Tags: r

Olá ! Tenho um problema na minha condição no ciclo while . Ele não reconhece quando deve parar e fica num loop infinito.O objetivo da funçao é contar o que esta entre "a" "t" "g" e "t" "a" "g" ou "t" "g" "a" ou "t" "a" "a".Se alguém puder ajudar agradecia :) .

```
  orfs<-function(x,p){
  count<-0
  cntorfs<-0
  n<-length(x)
  v<-n-2
  for (i in 1:v){
 if(x[i]=="a"&& x[i+1]=="t"&& x[i+2]=="g"){
  k<-i+3;
  w<-x[k]
  y<-x[k+1]
  z<-x[k+2]
  while (w!="t"&&y!="a"&& z!="g" ||w!="t" &&y!="a"&&z!="a"||w!="t"&&y!="g"&& z!="a"){
    count<-count+1
    k<-k+1
    w<-x[k]
    y<-x[k+1] 
    z<-x[k+2]
  }
  }
if(count>p){
  cntorfs<-cntorfs+1 
} 
if (count!=0){
  count<-0
}
}
cat("orf:",cntorfs)
`insira o código aqui`}
```

Comment: Este código deveria detectar um ORF numa sequência genética? Porque se for isso, eu aposto que tem funções no R que vão fazer este trabalho de maneira mais rápida, sem precisar reinventar a roda.

Comment: Sim é para contar ORFs . O exercício que a minha professora deu mandava fazer uma função que conta-se os ORFs presentes num código genético. Este código genético veio de um ficheiro FASTA.

Comment: O exercício pede que seja usado um loop? É possível trabalhar com sequência genética como string de texto, usando funções como strsplit e length para isolar e verificar o tamanho de sequências.

Comment: Não , mas entretanto eu já construi um código que teóricamente encontra os Orfs. Tive que trocar o meu ciclo "for" por um "while".

Comment: Veja o pacote [LncFinder](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/LncFinder/index.html).